# Resizable panel/grid for Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: user-interface, windows-10

I need to make a resizable side panel (intended to display numerous properties and tools) for my Windows 10 Universal App. I found there is a GridSplitter for WPF apps, but it seems this control doesn't work for Win10 Apps. Is there any other way how to achieve this functionality?